# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. cors error not resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://apicredit2fa.devserver.co.in/api/adminaccount/signin' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values **'*, *'**, but only one is allowed.

I cofigured the default cores and using middleware `app.UseCors();` as well

I tried with fixed cores but getting ***** and core name . multiple error remains

Comment: please add more detail from your code. for example, add your **startup.cs**.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
> *', but only one is allowed.

indicates there're mutipule `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` in your response headers

and if you configured `AllowAnyOrigin()` when you regist cros,it would add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' :"*"` to your response header,
try remove `AllowAnyOrigin()` and observe if there're any other error or check if you added the header anwhere else again

If you still have problem,please show us a minimal example that could reproduce the error

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try this

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
            });
```

and below consume this policy It works

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: I am using the same but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved. problem was nginx proxy server that was adding extra header value.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following nginx configuration items: `proxy_hide_header` `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`;
This problem bothered me for a day, I used `nginx` forwarding, domain name forwarding to the corresponding *ip address*, and finally found in: https://juejin.cn/post/6995374680114741279